# how to start artificial-intelligence programming?

Tags: prolog, artificial-intelligence

hi I am currently a `PHP` developer . I haven't done any thing in artificial intelligence but  I like to start artificial intelligence programming . I know there a are languages like `LISP` , `PRO-LOG` .

how do I get started ??

can you suggest me some E books .
some study guide lines .
what are the IDE s that I can use .

please help . thanks ............

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=artificial+intelligence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not ebooks, but real books for learning the basics of Prolog and classic IA:

- "Prolog Programming for Artificial Intelligence" by Ivan Bratko
- "The Art of Prolog" by Leon Sterling

Regarding IDE's, SWI-Prolog is probably the most friendly free Prolog system with integrated graphical editor, profiler and debugger. Though, Emacs and vi are probably what most Prolog programmers use for editing Prolog programs.